# Mirror javascript object in localStorage?

Tags: javascript

Currently I use the following methods to keep a variable and local storage the same. I use load on every pageload and save on any updates to the variable

```
viewed = Utils.load('viewed') || {};


..utils

      load: function(item) {
        if(localStorage.getItem(item)){
          return JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem(item));
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      },

      save: function(name, content) {
        localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(content));
      },
```

Is there a better way to keep a variable in sync with local storage?

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? Not having to manually call load/save? If so, then look at Object.observe() in ES6. There's probably a library that implements that in ES5.

Comment: @UAvalos Was not aware of this. This is amazing. Too bad it's not supported in most browsers currently.

Comment: How could you possibly implement `Object.observe` in ES5? By definition it requires engine involvement.

Comment: @Sinistralis there are polyfills libraries that bring ES6/7 support to ES5. For example, a quick search, yields https://github.com/joelgriffith/object-observe-es5